# How can I render my 2D background under the water with opengles

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, effect

I am rendering my 2D background under the water with opengles. How can I distort my textures over time? I just know to achive this with sin(time) or cos(time). But I'm poor in glsl.I have no idea how to do it. Shoud I changed the x,y coordination over time? How can I avoid move the whole texture repeatedly?
Any help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may distort the texture coordinates in hope of achieving this but you will need a few parameters.

For instance you can use a sin or cos function (not much of a difference between them) to distort horizontally by moving the `X` texture coordinate by a small amount. So you insert for instance an uniform (`strength`) which should be relative to the texture for instance `.1` will distort for a maximum of 10%. Then the idea would be to set `X=sin(Y)*strength`. Since the `Y` is in range from 0 to 1 you will need to add another parameter such as `density` to get "more waves" which should be in range like 20 for instance to get a few waves (change this as you please to test for a nice effect). So then the equation becomes `X=sin(Y*density)*strength`. Still this will produce a static distorted image but what you want is to move over time so you need some vertical time factor `delta` which should be changed over time and range between `.0` and `2*PI` and then the equation is `X=sin(Y*density + delta)*strength`. On every frame you should increase the `delta` and if it is larger then `2*PI` simply decrease it by `2*PI` to get a smooth animation. The value you increase the `delta` by will control the speed of the effect.

So now you have 3 uniform parameters which you should try to play around to get the desired effect. I hope you find it.